# Python rename files in subdirectory with subdirectory name

Tags: python

I have a directory which contains many subdirectories, and each subdirectory contains many files.  There are specific files that I want to copy and they all share the same name.  The way to distinguish is the subdirectory name.  Example:

```
parent/$date/subdirectory1/file.foo
parent/$date/subdirectory2/file.foo
```

I want to copy all the file.foo to a new location and rename them date_subdirectory1_file.foo

I tried using os.rename but that only worked for one file at a time and I can't figure out a recursive with the date and subdirectories as params

Comment: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with a bash script

```
shopt -u globstar
for csv in **/file.foo; do
  mv "$csv" "${csv//\//_}"
done
```